# Sorting Woocommerce products with numeric titles

Tags: loop, order, plugins

Just started playing around with Woocommerce, ran into a problem. I have a bunch of items (100+) and all of them only have a number as product title, 1,2,3 etc. The problem is that Woocommerce outputs the products like this: 1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20 – and so forth. How can I make it output correctly?

Comment: Seems completely valid to me. Yes, he's saying Woocommerce but it's a WP_Query question at the heart of it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either have to sort/order your products manually or create a custom sort order within WooCommerce. For that take a look at the WooCommerce docs and [this snippet](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/) for doing just that.

In this case you're also going to have to do a bit of MySQL manipulation as well so that you're sorting the *numbers* numerically. See this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939518/sorting-string-column-containing-numbers-in-sql) for an example.

**NOTE:** You may have some performance issues with the MySQl as a result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-change-order-of-catalog-page-to-ascending but I didn't seem to work (The order didn't change when switching between asc/desc). What could be wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your exact code and perhaps a URL I could only guess. But my answer is two part, you still have to account for the MySQL portion to sort as you want to.

Comment: I realize it's impossible for you to know what's wrong for my particular install. I will try and work with the MySQL solution instead. Could you please elaborate a little on how I can filter the results via MySQL for Woocommerce? I'm not sure where I should put any code or tie in with Woocommerce for this matter.

Comment: Is your site publicly accessible? Can you share the URL so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.